# Two different morphism of $K$-schemes have different image points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

If $K$ is a field and $X\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}K$ a $K$-scheme, and I have two morphisms of $K$-schemes $f_1,f_2:\operatorname{Spec} K\rightarrow X$ that are different, does it follow that $f_1$ and $f_2$ have different image points? (I came along this question while trying to understand the proof of Görtz/Wedhorn Prop. 4.35.)

Comment: If they don't have different images, then they must land in one affine chart. And the question should be easy for affine X.

Comment: @Serge Thank your for the hint. Say we have image point $x\in \operatorname{Spec}A\subseteq X$, and $f_i$ corresponds to $\varphi_i:A\rightarrow K$, then we have that $\varphi_1\neq\varphi_2$ and $K\rightarrow A\stackrel{\varphi_i}{\rightarrow}K=\operatorname{id}_K.$ However, if we had $A=K\times K$ and the structure morphism $K\rightarrow A$ is the diagonal, and $\varphi_i$ is the projection onto the $i$-th factor, I don't see how we get a contardiction...? So the statement above is wrong, or am I mistaken?

Comment: The idea is that in the affine case you can switch to studying maps of $K$-algebras, and the image point of a morphism will correspond to the kernel of a $K$-algebra map. So you only need to check if there can be 2 different $K$-algebra morphisms with identical kernels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "..does it follow that f1 and f2 have different image points?"

**Answer:** Let $X:=Spec(A)$ and let $\mathfrak{m}_i:=ker(f_i) \subseteq A$ be the kernel of $f_i$. By definition: the topological space of $Spec(A)$ is the set of prime ideals in $A$.
If $f_1\neq f_1$ there is an element $x\in A$ with $f_1(x)\neq f_2(x)$. Let $a:=f_1(x)$.
It follows $f_1(x-a)=0$ and $f_2(x-a)\neq 0$ hence $a\in \mathfrak{m}_1, a\notin \mathfrak{m}_2$ hence $\mathfrak{m}_1 \neq \mathfrak{m}_2$. By definition: If you view the maps $f_i$ as maps of schemes you get the following:

$$Im(f_i):=\{\mathfrak{m}_i\} \subseteq X$$

and it follows $Im(f_1) \neq Im(f_2)$.